# Validation Alpha text in Yii?

Tags: yii

I want to validate text contains only alpha and number then only it will save in Db.

Saving my postcode column have text and number then only it will save ,

for example,
postcode like 67898 means it will show error your text contain alphanumeric

postcode like GB means it will show error your text contain alphanumeric

postcode like GB789 it only save.how to valiadtion text contain both number and alpha in Yii?

Using Yii1.

Comment: yii1 or yii2  please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for yii1 you can use  match validation  rules

```
  array(
        'username, password',
        'match', 'pattern' => '/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/',
        'message' => 'Invalid characters in your column.',
    ),
```

Comment: i want to validate both letter and number not only letter,check user enter both letter and number then only it will save,else showing validation error

Comment: I have update the answer .. with alpha lowercase and uppercase and digit

Comment: thanx for ur response,am using yii1,but above code it will save without letters.

Comment: /^[A-Z]{1-*}\d{1-*}$/ if you don't mind can you plz explain me the preg match, It will not save it showing always validation error Am passing data like GB6789.

Comment: I have changed the reg_exp ... hope this is what you need

Comment: Thanx for your response,Got it.